# Set background of image to 0 - Skimage

Tags: python, mask, scikit-image

I am using Skimage v0.14

I would like to do the inverse of this piece of code

```
image[leaf_cleaned] = 0
```

Here I am setting the masked area to 0, what I actually want is everything but the masked area to be 0, or any number.

here is the rest of my code:

```
image = imread('')

grey_image = rgb2grey(image)
entireLeaf = feature.canny(grey_image) 

blurred = filters.gaussian(entireLeaf, sigma=0.4)  


fillleaf = ndi.binary_fill_holes(blurred) 

label_objects, nb_labels = ndi.label(fillleaf) 
sizes = np.bincount(label_objects.ravel()) 
mask_sizes = sizes > 100000             
mask_sizes[0] = 0
leaf_cleaned = mask_sizes[label_objects]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `leaf_cleaned` is a boolean-array [like used for masks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays), you can just do:

```
image[~leaf_cleaned] = 0
```

which follows numpy's [boolean-indexing docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).

Keep in mind, that sklearn is heavily based on numpy! So numpy's docs are often relevant!

Comment: Perfect, thank you, sir/madame! I knew there was a way to do it I just couldn't figure it out. Thanks again.